# Ember Handlebars template conditionally pass some attribute

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a custom grid component and I am trying to implement a custom header (passed in as argument to my-grid)
However, I want the "customHeader" to be conditional. i.e. only if some condition is true, do I need to add that attribute, else that attribute should not be set/passed at all.
Is it possible to achieve this within the Handlebars template itself?

```
{{#my-grid
    model=myModel
    customHeader=(component 'my-custom-grid-header')
    as |grid|}}

{{/my-grid}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. The list of arguments passed to a component is defined at build time.

However what you could do is this:

```
customHeader=(if @something (component 'my-custom-grid-header') null)
```

Then if `{{#if @customHeader}}` is used inside the component it will be `false`.

However `Object.keys(this.args)` inside a glimmer component will always contain `customHeader`. There is no way to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

It's verbose, but if you really don't want to pass it you could do:

```
{{#if customeHeader}}
  {{#my-grid
    model=myModel
    customHeader=(component 'my-custom-grid-header')
    as |grid|}}
  {{/my-grid}}
{{else}}
  {{#my-grid
    model=myModel
    as |grid|}}
  {{/my-grid}}
{{/if}}
```